# Is there a way to filter based on dates in Bing Webmaster API calls?

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-webmaster-tools

I am trying to fetch some page stats using GetPageStats method in IWebmasterApi for a url. It returns stats for all the dates. Is there a way to set filter on dates we want the date for? I am sending a GET request through Postman and not using c# program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I found it is not possible to do a date filter in Bing API calls. Everytime, the entire data (3 months approx) of page stats is sent. The date filter has to be handled in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Not sure this is answering your question, I just start "digging" to develop some app for my use, normally first I read where people complain and fail.

there is some date filter...

You need to see what is the request in C# easy... then reverse engineering and build it in Postman

```
  var oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
  var stats = api.GetRankAndTrafficStats("http://yoursite.com/")
       .Where(s => s.Date > oneMonthAgo)
        .OrderBy(s => s.Date);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingwebmaster/getting-started

```
namespace WebmasterApiExamples
{
   using System;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.ServiceModel;

   internal class Program
   {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var api = new WebmasterApi.WebmasterApiClient();

        try
        {
            var oneMonthAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
            var stats = api.GetRankAndTrafficStats("http://yoursite.com/")
                .Where(s => s.Date > oneMonthAgo)
                .OrderBy(s => s.Date);
            Console.WriteLine("Date\tImpressions\tClicks");
            foreach (var value in stats)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", value.Date.ToShortDateString(), value.Impressions, value.Clicks);
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException<WebmasterApi.ApiFault> fault)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to add site: {0}", fault.Message);
        }
       }
   }
}
```